# knife interactive commands EDITOR

Tags: chef-infra

I need to create a data bag using `knife`.

I've set this line in `knife.rb` file:

```
knife[:editor] = 'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe'
```

This is my `knife.rb` content file:

```
knife[:editor] = 'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe'
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "living"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/cert.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://api.chef.io/organizations/company"
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
```

However, when I perform `knife data bag create aws main`, I'm getting this message:

```
Data bag aws already exists
ERROR: RuntimeError: Please set EDITOR environment variable
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `'C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe -w'`, i.e. correcting the backslash escaping and adding "wait mode".

Comment: Thanks @coderanger. It keeps failing and the message is the same. Why some properties has an `property = value` syntax and other ones `property value` (without `=`)?

Comment: I've tried setting `knife[:editor] = 'notepad'` and it works fine now...

Comment: The different syntax is because some are DSL methods, others are local variables, and some are a Hash-based config system. Are you use your `knife.rb` is in the correct place?